# AWS Lambda javascript-sdk , implementing dynamodb putItem method receive timeout

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have tried on both `Async Handlers` and `Non-Async Handlers` ways,
to implement dynamodb putItem method. it returned an invalid response.
Its works for commented setTimeout function.

I tried by  promisify the dynomodb putItem method in Non-Async Handler way as mentioned and official documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html. But still no luck.
can some one point me out the issue on code?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ 
    region: 'ap-south-1',
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10'
});

exports.lambdaHandler = async function(event) {
    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        // setTimeout(function(){
        //     console.log("resolvedx")
        //     resolve({statusCode: 200, body: "resolvedx"})
        // }, 200)

        dynamodb.putItem({
            TableName: 'CUSTOMER_LIST',
            Item: {
                'CUSTOMER_ID': { N: '012' },
                'CUSTOMER_NAME': { S: 'zzzza' }
            }
        }
        , function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("err", err);
                reject(JSON.stringify({statusCode:200, body:err}));
            } else {
                console.log("success", data);
                resolve(JSON.stringify({statusCode:200, body:data}));
            }
        })
    })

    return promise
}
```

as `Non-Async Handlers`

```
exports.lambdaHandlerx = (event, context, callback) => {


    const dbPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        console.log("inside db promise")
        dynamodb.putItem({
                TableName: 'CUSTOMER_LIST',
                Item: {
                    'CUSTOMER_ID': { N: '023' },
                    'CUSTOMER_NAME': { S: 'asdddwa' }
                }
            }
            , function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("err", err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("success", data);
                    resolve(data);
                }
            })
    })

    Promise.all([dbPromise()]).then(data => {
        console.log("then", data)
        callback(null, {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': JSON.stringify({
                message: "dataxz"+ JSON.stringify(data)
            })
        })
     }
    ).catch(e => {
        callback(null, {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': JSON.stringify({
                message: 'err'
            })
        })
    })


}
```

Output

```
Function returned an invalid response (must include one of: body, headers, multiValueHeaders or statusCode in the response object). Response received:
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from your async lambda. Have a look [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/) for more info.

Comment: in async function(example 1) I have returned the Promise at the end, isn't it valid?